# Store in secondary table or UNLOAD column information from Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a need to retrieve the column size for VARCHAR fields in a Redshift database for all tables.  I can easily see that in client by running something like:

```
SELECT      
    t.table_schema
  , t.table_name
  , c.column_name
  , udt_name
  , character_maximum_length

FROM
     information_schema.tables t
JOIN information_schema.columns c 
  ON c.table_name = t.table_name 
 AND c.table_schema = t.table_schema
```

However as information_schema queries run only on the leader node I cannot perform an UNLOAD, store the results in another table, or utilize a join to another table.

I need to establish a process that runs daily, so manually copying the data isn't an option.  Very much appreciate any advice.